# javascript get file contents

Tags: javascript, file-get-contents

I would like to know it there is something in JavaScript that loads the contents of a given file. For example, I have a file called `timer.php` which on certain conditions it prints either a `1` or a `0` and I need JavaScript to read it and use it as a variable in order to execute a function.

So something like:

```
function dothis() {

 var timer = getfilecontents(timer.php);

 if(timer == 1) {
   somefunction();
 }
}
```

And thats pretty much it. What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

try again AJAX

dothis

```
<script>
function dothis(){
    $.ajax({
        type: 'get',
        cache: false,
        url: 'http://example.com/timer.php',
        beforeSend:function() {
            console.log('loading...');
        },
        success: function(response) {
            console.log(response)
        }
    });
}
</script>
```

Comment: JavaScript doesn't have a `$` object with an `.ajax` property.

Comment: It's Jquery include <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script> in head tag

Comment: Thank you but is it necessary that much code? Is that as simple as it can get?

Comment: @SurjitSidhu: OP probably doesn't know what jQuery is. Either way, there's no indication he's using it.

Comment: @Nuker: While it can be simpler, that is extremely simple.

Comment: @Nuker with core javascript it will be more then 3 times a code of above

Comment: Okay, i thought it was something as simple as getfilecontents(); or so. Anyway, the way to use your code is like: var = dothis();

Comment: It's entirely wrong to say that a pure JS solution will take more than 3 times  the code as you provided. That has no basis in reality whatsoever, and is the typical rhetoric of jQuery users who simply don't know how to do anything without it. So please don't spread blatantly false information.